# How can I make the Laravel5 Codeception module not care if my database entities are Eloquent models?

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, eloquent, codeception

I'm updating our codebase to use Laravel 5.2 which includes a bunch of unit tests that use codeception. Originally, the code was written using plain Doctrine2, which I updated to use LaravelDoctrine. With that change came the need to update the tests to use the codeception Laravel5 module.

Now, the tests were originally written as such

```
public function someTest(SomeTestObject $I) {
        $I->wantTo('Some test objective');

        $I->amOnPage('/some/page.php?parameter=678');
        $I->waitForText('Text');

        $I->click('Somelink');    

        $I->seeInRepository('My/Models/SomeObject', ['columnName' => 678]);
}
```

and they work and [everything is awesome](https://youtu.be/StTqXEQ2l-Y?t=5s).

Once I updated to use the Laravel5 module, The `$I->seeInRepository(...` isn't generated by codeception in the `AcceptanceTesterActions.php` file, so I can't use it anymore. I tried a couple other methods that were there instead -- `canSeeReord`, `seeInDatabase` -- but they throw the exception

```
[RuntimeException] Class SomeObject is not an Eloquent model
```

I understand that because `SomeObject` actually *isn't* an Eloquent model but... who cares? The test worked before, and using the website works everywhere (LaravelDoctrine's tagline is "A drop-in Doctrine2 implementation for Laravel 5+" which it sort of is so that's cool).

We have a ton of models and some complicated structure to the current model set to which a complete rewrite simply isn't in scope...

I looked at the module code in Laravel5.php, and the exception and module looks pretty coupled to Eloquent models:

```
/**
 * @param string $modelClass
 *
 * @return EloquentModel
 */
protected function getQueryBuilderFromModel($modelClass)
{
    $model = new $modelClass;

    if (!$model instanceof EloquentModel) {
        throw new \RuntimeException("Class $modelClass is not an Eloquent model");
    }

    return $model->newQuery();
}
```

Is there a way around this?

Comment: I think that correct solution is to add `_getEntityManager` method to Laravel5 module and use it in combination with Doctrine module.

Comment: Look at Symfony and ZF2 modules for examples of implementation. Please make a pull request to Codeception.

Comment: I checked out the old codebase using `Doctrine2`, which implements `_getEntityManager()` from `DoctrineProvider`... never gets called. When does that call happen?

Comment: It is called by Doctrine2 module: https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/blob/2.2.9/src/Codeception/Module/Doctrine2.php#L131
You have to set `depends: Laravel5` too.